# Print up to 2 decimal places. I only know this method and get it wrong for the next code

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math
a = 19
b = math.sqrt(19)
print("%.4f"%(b))
#print(a.4f) error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"%.4f" % (b)` method of formatting strings is rarely used nowadays. Python has introduced string formatting such as (Python 2.6+):

```
"{:.2f}".format(b)
```

and f-strings (Python 3.6+):

```
f"{b:.2f}"
```

Both of these will give you two digits after the decimal point. The first has the advantage (over `string % args`) of allowing argument re-use and also avoiding the foibles of `string % args` in terms of using tuples and such.

The second also has those advantages but also brings the arguments inline to the string so it's easier to figure out what is being printed (you don't have to look at `{17}` and then go looking at the 18th argument of the `format` call).

Comment: The `f` before your `f` string seems to be missing. And your first method isn't correct usage (results in `KeyError`. It should be `"{:.2f}".format(b)`. An optional index or key can be put before the colon and used as an identifier in the arguments for format.

Comment: Thanks, @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica, serves me right for trying to answer C and Python questions too close to each other :-) Fixed now (I hope).

Comment: import math
sq=[]
n=int(input())
for adad in range(0,n):
    number=float(input())
    a=str(math.sqrt(number))
    x,y=a.split('.')
    if y=="0":
        y=y+"000"
    adade_jadid=x+"."+y[:4]
    sq.append(adade_jadid)
for adad in sq:
    print(adad)